# How can I add long text in ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net, contentplaceholder, longtext

I'm working with Asp.net. My problem is adding long text inside ContentPlaceHolder. I want to create scrollbar. Which way should I use?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't?  Is it wrapping when you dont' want it to?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you want to achieve.  Is it a vertical or horizontal scrollbar that you want?  Is the problem getting the scrollbar to appear, or is it the more basic problem of how to make something appear in a `ContentPlaceHolder`?

Comment: My long text spill over content area.I created table in ContentPlaceHolder and I arrange table style as "overflow-y:auto;" but I didn't get resault. I want to add text and then scrollbar should appear only when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it sounds like you have the usage of the `Content` and `ContentPlaceHolder` tags mixed up.  The `ContentPlaceHolder` goes where you want the content to appear, but is itself left empty.  You put the content that you want to have appear in place of the `ContentPlaceHolder` inside the `Content` tag.  So your table should be inside the `Content` tag, not inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` tag.

Second, you might get better results (the appearance of a vertical scrollbar on a table) if you surrounded the table by a DIV tag and put `overflow-y:auto;` on the DIV rather than the table.  It would look like this (assuming inline styles):

```
 <div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow-y:auto;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Information</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Finally, since you didn't mention it, I'll point it out:  in order for the overflow handling to work, you need to specify a fixed height for the DIV (as I do above).  If it doesn't know it's supposed to be a certain height, it can't determine when it has overflowed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's what I'm looking for.Thank you so much Ann. This helped me alot!